# How to keep track of the initial head pointer in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to append at the end of the list and return **head** at the end of this function.

This is a singly linked list. So, I have lost my head after traversing to the end.

**file.c**

```
#define NAME_LEN 30

struct equipment{
    char type[NAME_LEN+1];
    char description[NAME_LEN+1];
    int quantity;
    struct equipment *next;
};

struct equipment *append_to_list(struct equipment *list){
  char type[NAME_LEN + 1], description[NAME_LEN + 1];
  int quantity;

  printf("Enter equipment type: ");
  fgets(type, NAME_LEN, stdin);

  printf("Enter description of the equipment: ");
  fgets(description, NAME_LEN, stdin);

  printf("Enter quantity: ");
  scanf("%d", &quantity);

  struct equipment *temp = (struct equipment *)malloc(sizeof(struct equipment));

  strcpy(temp->type, type);
  strcpy(temp->description, description);
  temp->quantity = quantity;
  temp->next = NULL;

  bool doesExist = false;

  if ( list == NULL ){
    list = temp;
  }
  else{
    while ( list->next != NULL ){
      if ( list == temp ){
        printf("This equipment is already in the list\n");
      }
      list = list->next;
    }
    list->next = temp;
  }
  // return head of this list here;
}
```

In this int main function, **e_list** should point to head of the linked list after calling **append_to_list(e_list)**.

```
int main(void)
{
   struct equipment *e_list = NULL;
   e_list = append_to_list(e_list);

}
```

How do I create a reference and traverse that dummy head? That way I never lose my original head.

Comment: Your question is unclear for seemingly asking about how to create and use a local variable. Please explain more about what keeps you from using that obvious solution.

Comment: Create a new specific "list" structure, containing pointers to the head and the tail? Might make things easier if you often need to access the tail.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have updated with more details. Please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a temporary variable, in the `else` add

```
struct equipment *tmp;
tmp = list;
```

And replace all occurrences of `list` in the `else`. At the end return you `list` variable.

Comment: Why not initialize the variable in contrary to affect it => `struct equipment *tmp = list;` is a lot better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already putting the newly created `structure` `temp` at the **end**. Your **head** will not change between different calls in `main` because the **head** is at the opposite side of the **end**.

You need a static variable to keep track of head. Here is the tested code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN 30

struct equipment
{
  char type[NAME_LEN + 1];
  char description[NAME_LEN + 1];
  int quantity;
  struct equipment *next;
};

struct equipment *
append_to_list (struct equipment *list)
{
  char type[NAME_LEN + 1], description[NAME_LEN + 1];
  int quantity;

  printf ("Enter equipment type: ");
  fgets (type, NAME_LEN, stdin);

  printf ("Enter description of the equipment: ");
  fgets (description, NAME_LEN, stdin);

  printf ("Enter quantity: ");
  scanf ("%d", &quantity);

  struct equipment *temp =
    (struct equipment *) malloc (sizeof (struct equipment));

  strcpy (temp->type, type);
  strcpy (temp->description, description);
  temp->quantity = quantity;
  temp->next = NULL;

  bool doesExist = false;
  static struct equipment * head = NULL;  //New variable

  if (list == NULL)
    {
      list = temp;
      head = list;
    }
  else
    {
      while (list->next != NULL)
    {
      if (list == temp)
        {
          printf ("This equipment is already in the list\n");
        }
      list = list->next;
    }
      list->next = temp;
    }
    return head;        //return head here
}

int main()
{
    struct equipment *e_list = NULL;
    e_list = append_to_list(e_list);
    e_list = append_to_list(e_list);
    e_list = append_to_list(e_list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `list!=NULL`, head will always be == to NULL !!

Comment: At the start, list will always be NULL, as done inside main(), because e_list will start with NULL.

Comment: Yes, and the second time you will be in the function, list will not be NULL, so you will return a NULL pointer; And e_list will be NULL, which will cause a memory leak !

Comment: No in the second time the function will **not** return NULL because `head` is a static variable and it was already initialized to some non NULL value previously.

Comment: 'static': not thread safe..

Comment: And if you have multiple list, head will be set to the head of the la NULL list in which you added en element. So if you add an element to a previous list you will lose their reference, which, in this case, lead to memory leak. :)

Answer (score 0):

You really could do a few things here.

Firstly though, your code is rather unsafe. Your buffers are far too small, don't use scanf to convert an integer (it doesn't check for failure), and don't use strcpy (especially when your buffers are tiny). Also, the calls to printf are a bit pointless if you're just using a literal string - puts() should be considered instead - and don't cast the return from malloc(). This is maybe a bit safer.

```
#include <bsd/bsd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_LEN 32
#define nputs(STR) fputs((STR), stdout)

struct equipment {
    char type[NAME_LEN];
    char description[NAME_LEN];
    int quantity;
    struct equipment *next;
};

struct equipment *
append_to_list(struct equipment *list)
{
    char type[BUFSIZ], description[BUFSIZ], quantity_string[BUFSIZ];
    int quantity;

    nputs("Enter equipment type: ");
    fgets(type, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    nputs("Enter description of the equipment: ");
    fgets(description, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    nputs("Enter quantity: ");
    fgets(quantity_string, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    char *endptr;
    quantity = strtol(quantity_string, &endptr, 10);
    if (quantity_string == endptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid integer input '%s'\n", quantity_string);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct equipment *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);

    strlcpy(temp->type, type, NAME_LEN);
    strlcpy(temp->description, description, NAME_LEN);
    temp->quantity = quantity;
    temp->next     = NULL;

    bool doesExist = false;

    if (list == NULL) {
        list = temp;
    } else {
        while (list->next != NULL) {
            if (list == temp)
                puts("This equipment is already in the list");
            list = list->next;
        }
        list->next = temp;
    }
    // return head of this list here;
}
```

As to keeping track of the head, you could use a different function to initialize the tree than to append to it, thus giving you a slightly unique root object. You could add a field to each struct that stores the location of the root, or you could make a separate struct entirely that holds the root and perhaps some metadata about it. There are plenty of options. I agree with a few of the comments above, it isn't entirely clear what you're asking for here.